# How to use refer to multiple id's when using JOINs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to display the number of reviews which an employee provided and the number of reviews which he received. I try to do something like this, but in my output table (3) I receive incorrect data. I believe that this happens due to the wrong reference:

```
pr.reviewer_id = e.employee_id
```

however, if I reference it like this:

```
pr.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

then `nr_of_reviews_receieved` is correct and `nr_of_reviews_posted` is not, and if I change it back it's vice versa. So, I need in one case to use one reference and in another a different one, but all in one query.

```
SELECT 
    e.employee_id, 
    CONCAT_WS(' ',employee_first_name, employee_last_name) AS full_name,
    COUNT(pr.reviewer_id) AS nr_of_reviews_posted,
    COUNT(pr.employee_id) AS nr_of_reviews_received
FROM 
    employee AS e
LEFT JOIN 
    performance_review AS pr ON pr.reviewer_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY 
    employee_first_name, employee_last_name, e.employee_id
```

[image: employee table]

[image: performance_reviews table]

[image: my output table]

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough info to answer. Tell us about your table structure

Comment: You need to join review table twice. Once for reviews made by and second -   who is reviewed.

Comment: @KarlisFersters - Sounds right.  You should post answer.

Comment: Tip: Posting screen shots makes it harder for others to assist, because they can't copy the text.  Please post data samples as text, in tabular format.

Comment: Thank you @Karlis Fersters, I added one more join, and referenced the alias with different name, changed first count to the first alias reference, and the second, to the second one, and its shows as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sample the tables twice and join to the table each time
for example:

```
SELECT 
e.employee_id, 
CONCAT_WS(' ',employee_first_name, employee_last_name) AS full_name,
COUNT(pr.reviewer_id) AS nr_of_reviews_posted,
COUNT(pr2.employee_id) AS nr_of_reviews_received
FROM 
employee AS e
LEFT JOIN 
performance_review AS pr ON pr.reviewer_id = e.employee_id
LEFT JOIN 
performance_review AS pr2 ON pr2.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY 
Necessary columns ...
```